# How to link a HTML page to a button in Laravel 5.1. I am new to PHP very new to Laravel and this community

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to link a separate signup page with the signup button using laravel, it's showing:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:error
```

The page resides in the `resources/views` folder. And the html in in `resources/views/includes`.

Comment: You need to set route first

Comment: I have already created the home page. and set the routes.php to Route::get('/', function () { return view('home'); });. now the home page is lying in the views folder and properly working. there in a nav bar button as signup and I have a signup page as 'firstsignup.blade.php', the path is resources/views the problem is i am inept to link the signup page using the url {{URL::to('resources/views/firstsignup')}}. please guide what do i need to do in the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got answer to my problem.

The routes.php should have:

```
    Route::get('/signup', function () {return view('actions.firstsignup');})->name('firstsignup');
```

here     '/signup' is the http identity for the page. 'actions' is the sub-folder in views where the destination file is stored, file-name is firstsignup.blade.php and ->name('firstsignup') is route definition.

Now I have put link in the button as:

```
    href="{{route('firstsignup')}}
```

Thanks a lot guys for helping me clearing it conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

http/routes.php

```
Route::get('/register', 'HomeController@getRegister');
```

Controllers/HomeController.php

```
public function getRegister() 
{
    return view('admin.register');   
}
```

Comment: admin is a folder name and register is my view

Answer (score 0):

The URL of your sign-up page is not added in the `routes.php` file, add it in the file as:

```
Route::get('/signup','yourController@sign_up_function');
```

Comment: that's wrong...you need to create route first, the route will point to a function in controller and then from controller you will need to render view file

Comment: I have already created the home page. Route::get('/', function () { return view('home'); });. now the home page is lying in the views folder and properly working. the problem is i am inept to link the signup page.

Comment: change .`Route::get('/',` to `. Route::get('/signup',` and add ahref as ` a href='domain.com/signup'` ..try it and let me know whether it worked or not

Comment: just try one thing..i have got what you are doing...try this..`<?=URL::to('/')."/signup" =>` and add the sign up link in route.php as  `Route::get('/', function () { return view('signup'); });`

Comment: Thanks, I tried using this earlier it worked. the only problem is i want my default page to be the home page. but after  Route::get('/', function () { return view('signup'); }); the default page is the signup page.

Comment: add 2 routes.. one as  `get('/', function () { return view('home'); });` and another one as `:get('/signup', function () { return view('signup'); });`

Comment: set  routes like this  Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); and call view from index method

Comment: Thanks a lot!! for the extended help

Comment: what did you try? @Chandraarnav

Comment: I tried first 'get('/signup', function () { return view('signup'); });' its showing syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ';' ... then I tried Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); this one worked. Thanks so much.